# Открыть браузер Edge с Proxy с помощью Python

Tags: python-3.x, bat, автоматизация, pyautogui

Использую библиотеку pyautogui + webbrowser. Сразу скажу что Selenium и Requests не подойдут.
Как открыть браузер уже с использованием proxy? Возможно даже использование subprocess + os, не суть, но главное я хочу открыть браузер уже с прокси!

Answer (score 0):

Данная программа запустит прокси на твоём ПК/сервере:

```
import socketserver
import http.server
import urllib

PORT = 9097

class MyProxy(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        url=self.path[1:]
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(url), self.wfile)


httpd = socketserver.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), MyProxy)
print ("Now serving at", str(PORT))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Или тебе надо прям подключение уже к известному прокси?